# How to use data collect from lidar to generate a 2d map with

Tags: ros, navigation, lidar, mapping

I'm new to robotics and I'm using ros noetic with the package rp_lidar. I want to use the data collected from my a1m8 slamteck lidar and generate a 2d map for my rover to navigate and avoid collision. I added gmap slam package but I don't know how to set it up

Comment: You would better to take a look at the https://answers.ros.org/questions/

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Andres Rojas Jr, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.